# Nginx doesn't handle https redirection

Tags: nginx, https

When I access my page at www.example.com I get "Welcome to nginx" screen. 
It works ok if I type https://www.example.com but http or just www doesn't work or just example.com doesn't work either.
<strike>From a desktop computer I have no issues.</strike>

Here is my configuration:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name example.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    return  301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    server_name www.example.com;
    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        #proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
        proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8001;

    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias path/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {                        
        alias path/media/;
    }



    ssl_certificate path/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key path/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam path/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = 'example.com') {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    #I commented this out because the page stoped working with "too many redirects"
    #if ($host = 'www.example.com') {
    #   return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    #}

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Nothing in that Nginx config looks to be mobile specific. Try another phone / browser. Also, the line "if ($scheme != "https") {" is doing nothing as the block is port 443 only, which is pretty much always (99.9999% of the time) https.

Comment: My thoughts exactly but also on other devices this issues persists. The weird thing is also that without that if it doesn't work at all, not even on desktop. What I am doing wrong here? :-)

Comment: Ok, it is also a desktop issue. Somehow i always got a cached version of the page ... well so the configuration is not working for desktop and mobile.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific than "not working". http codes, error logs, screen shots, etc, if you want help.

Comment: I have written above that I get the "Welcome Nginx" page", there is no error code. It says the server s running but doesn't show my content when I enter via http, via https it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a server block which matches `http://www.example.com` so `nginx` will use the default server block. And many installations place a default server block in a file called `default` which shows the "Welcome to Nginx" page.

The simplest fix would be to allow `example.com` and `www.example.com` match your first `server` block by changing the `server_name` statement to:

```
server_name example.com www.example.com;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.